# PHP iconv_strlen question

Tags: php, utf-8, iconv

What does it mean when the icon_strlen fails on bad character sequences specifically `character sequences` is what I want to know. Thanks

Comment: Please show the code you are using, some example data, and what error you are getting exactly.

Comment: I just want to know what `character sequences` means but here is a link to what I'm talking about http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-strlen.php#62320

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `character sequence` is a series of bytes. When using UTF-8 not all combinations of bytes are valid.

The byte sequence `\xc2\xbc` forms the Unicode character `U+00BC` which is the `VULGAR FRACTION ONE QUARTER` symbol (¼) when using UTF-8 encoding.

The byte sequence `\xe2\x88\x9c` forms the Unicode character `U+221C` which is the `FOURTH ROOT` symbol (∜) when using UTF-8 encoding.

A bad character sequence for UTF-8 encoding would be any byte combination that doesn't fit into the required schema for [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) byte streams, e.g. the byte sequence `\xbc\xbc` would be illegal because two byte characters must have `110xxxxx` in the first byte but `\xbc` is `10111100` written as bits.